# count frequency by year with dplyr (conditional count)

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I want to count the use of Tool A by year and keep zeros.

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5)
Tool <- c("A","B","A","B","A","A","B","A","A","A")
Year <- c(2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2001,2000,2001,2002)
df <- data.frame(ID,Tool,Year)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(toolA = sum(Tool == "A")) %>% count(toolA)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  toolA     n
  <int> <int>
1     0     1
2     1     2
3     2     1
4     3     1
```

I want to add year columns, so that I can have a table as below

| tool A | Count | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The numbers under years means the number of use in a year.(Not a person)
How would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` method. Simply speaking, we would pivot the dataframe from wide to long and then summarize. Frist summarization gets rid of all the other non-`"A"`s. Second summarization condenses the result table into unique bins identified by each `toolA` and produces a `count`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(value = +(Tool == "A")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_fill = 0L) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(across(-Tool, sum)) %>% 
  group_by(toolA = rowSums(across(-ID))) %>% 
  summarize(count = n(), across(-c(ID, count), sum))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  toolA count `2000` `2001` `2002`
  <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     0     1      0      0      0
2     1     2      1      0      1
3     2     1      0      1      1
4     3     1      1      1      1
```

Comment: I have edited as I got errors with my real data. 

pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from=value, values_fn=sum) %>% 


Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too convoluted and a better/easier solution exists.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataA <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(toolA = sum(Tool == "A")) %>% 
  count(toolA)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Year) %>%
  summarise(toolA = sum(Tool == "A"), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = toolA, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  mutate(toolA = rowSums(.)) %>%
  right_join(dataA, by = 'toolA') %>%
  select(toolA, n, everything()) %>%
  arrange(toolA) %>%
  group_by(toolA, n) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = sum), .groups = 'drop')

#  toolA     n `2000` `2001` `2002`
#  <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     0     1      0      0      0
#2     1     2      1      0      1
#3     2     1      0      1      1
#4     3     1      1      1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I might try this approach with `tidyverse`. Create a list column with the `Year` when grouping by `ID`. After including the count `n` as you have done, use `unnest_longer` to recover the years. I added an extra column for situations where count is zero called "None". A final `pivot_wider` would put the data into wide form again.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(toolA = sum(Tool == "A"),
            Years = list(Year[Tool == "A"])) %>%
  add_count(toolA) %>%
  unnest_longer(Years) %>%
  replace_na(list(Years = "None")) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(toolA, n), names_from = Years, names_prefix = "Year_", values_from = value, values_fill = 0)%>%
  arrange(toolA)
```

**Output**

```
  toolA     n Year_2000 Year_2001 Year_2002 Year_None
  <int> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     0     1         0         0         0         1
2     1     2         1         0         1         0
3     2     1         0         1         1         0
4     3     1         1         1         1         0
```